# What does "by interpolation" mean and how to prove that $\vert x\vert^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is bounded from $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

It is known that $\vert x\vert^{-1}$ is bounded from $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and this can be shown using, for example, Hardy's inequality. Said that, I would you like someone help me to calrify the following statement. On my notes, I have written that this implies that $\vert x\vert^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is bounded from $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ by interpolation.

What does "by interpolation" mean? And how to show that $\vert x\vert^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is bounded from $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Could anyone help me? Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it should be $|x|^{-1/2}$ bounded from $H^{1/2}$ to $L^2$?

Yes, this is a result of interpolation theory. It is a theory that allows to find properties for intermediate spaces. There are two main settings: real and complex interpolation. You should look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space, or for example the book by Luc Tartar about "An Introduction to Sobolev Spaces and Interpolation Spaces" if you want to know more about it.

In your case, $H^{1/2}$ is the complex interpolation of $H^1$ and $L^2$ while the complex interpolation space between $L^2$ and $L^2$ with a weight $|x|^{-1}$ is the space $L^2$ with a weight $|x|^{-1/2}$. And you deduce the result by saying that the identity map is bounded between the two pair of spaces, and so also for the intermediate pair.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you eplain me in detail, by using the formulas in the link mentioned above, that $H^{1/2}$ is the complex interpolation of $H^1$ and $L^2$? And how to work with the weight? Sorry, it is still not so clear for me.

Comment: Finding the interpolation spaces between two spaces is generally not easy, or at least it is a bit long to write ... but most of them are known and can be found in courses and books on the subject. For example the interpolation of $H^s$ spaces is on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: The interpolation of weighted $L^p$ spaces can be found in a paper by J.E. Gilbert called ... "Interpolation between weighted $L^p$ spaces".

Comment: Thank you again @LL 3.14.

Comment: You can find the interpolation of $H^s$ spaces in the book by H. Triebel, "Theory of function spaces II", section 1.6.4.